# How can I avoid calling enqueueGet in my Sirius based application?

Tags: java, rest, distributed-computing

[Sirius](https://github.com/Comcast/sirius) is "a distributed system library for managing application reference data" written in Scala for the JVM. The aim of Sirius is to distribute a full copy of the data to every single node.

I have noticed that `enqueueGet` method is used for processing GET requests. This involves serializing all GET requests before they get processed. However, I want to try not serializing all my GETs to avoid read latency; is there a way I can avoid calling `enqueueGet`? If yes, how would I do that?

Comment: You are asking us to speculate about why someone else made a particular design decision.  This is unlikely to have a specific answer, and if it does you're likely to get one much faster on a Sirius-specific forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sirius library is designed so that each node has a complete copy of the data. This data is stored in memory and is available directly within the application. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Comcast/sirius/wiki/Getting+started+with+Sirius) the `enqueueGet` operation imposes overhead that may not be necessary. The enqueueGet operation will serialize the get request to be performed as soon as possible, generally right after the current operation finishes. This is a local serialization, it does not go through Paxos. Using enqueueGet prevents the application from performing concurrent gets and it also prevents the get from being performed while an update to the data is occurring.

So you will need to take care of two things:

1. Your application will need to be able to handle the concurrent GET operations itself. This may or may not be a problem depending on the nature of the data and the application.
2. Your application will need to be written such that a GET that is performed concurrently with a PUT or DELETE will not see a partially updated item. Your underlying data structure should not allow for the partial updates, or you will need to tolerate GETting a partial update.